# Elasticsearch check if script from file system is loaded

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting

I use Groovy scripts in elasticsearch's config/script directory to update/upsert.

As there are several nodes I would like to add a guard in the application code that the script is loaded/available and I need to document these steps with curl for admins.

I tried

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_scripts/groovy/<script_name>
```

which will just return indexed scripts - not the file system ones.

The closest I got is

```
curl localhost:9200/_search -d '
{
  "script_fields": {
    "<some_string_as_fieldname>": {
      "script_file": "<script_name>",
      "params": {
        "count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

which basically renders an exception `MissingPropertyException[No such property: ctx for class: Script2]]` because my script is an update-script requiring the `ctx`-variable. (During the update it works like charm.)

If it's not there, I get `nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Unable to find on disk script decrement_entity_e33]`

However, I guess there will be a more straight forward approach to check the script loaded. I just cannot find it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you have several nodes, using [indexed scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_indexed_scripts) might be a better idea to ensure the script is available on all your nodes.

Comment: It is okay for me to copy these scripts once to all instances.